# Call C++ dll in c# code

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am trying to call a C++ dll in C# code.
my header file -

```
#define MLTtest __declspec(dllexport)
class MLTtest testBuilder
{
public:
    testBuilder(void);
    ~testBuilder(void);


    int testfunc (int iNumber);
};
```

My .CPP Class

```
int testBuilder::testfunc (int iNumber)
{

    return iNumber*2 ;
}
```

Here is my C# code for using that dll.

```
class Program
{

    [DllImport(@"C:\Sources\Operations\Online.Dev\BIN\Debug\Mlt1090d64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "testfunc")]
    public static extern int testfunc(int n);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int x = testfunc (50);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

but I keep getting this exception exception:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'testfunc ' in DLL
>   'C:\Sources\Operations\Online.Dev\BIN\Debug\Mlt1090d64.dll'.

Comment: no thats not the reason i edited now . its copy paste mistake here :)

Comment: @Adrian response is the correct one... If you truly want to call C++ from C# (but note that it is brittle, it is a pain, and in the end it isn't really useful), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42552494/613130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you try to call a class member method.

Place in the .cpp file the flowing function (not a class member)

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) testfunc(int iNumber)
{
  return iNumber*2;
}
```

and update in the .cs

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Sources\Operations\Online.Dev\BIN\Debug\Mlt1090d64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int testfunc(int n);
```